# Parse string to TIMESTAMP BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a date stored as a string in this format:

```
Fri Jul 01 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
```

How can one convert it to TIMESTAMP in Google BigQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try and consider below approach:

```sql
select PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%a %b %d %Y %T %z', REGEXP_EXTRACT(
  REGEXP_REPLACE('Fri Jul 01 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)', r'GMT', ''), 
r'(^\w{3}\s\w{3}\s\d{1,2}\s\w{4}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\s\+\d{4}).+')) as timestamp_bq
```

**Output:**
[image]